# caracteres especiais html e mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, caracteres

Pessoal eu tenho sistema de cadastro de video via IFRAME porém quando quero mostrar o iframe ele fica em branco pois o banco de dados converteu

Codigo iframe original

```
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FMarvrikLIVE%2Fvideos%2F386994741992059%2F&show_text=1&width=560" width="560" height="483" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media" allowFullScreen="true">
```

No banco de dados

```
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FMarvrikLIVE%2Fvideos%2F386994741992059%2F&show_text=1&width=560&#34; width=&#34;560&#34; height=&#34;483&#34; style=&#34;border:none;overflow:hidden&#34; scrolling=&#34;no&#34; frameborder=&#34;0&#34; allowTransparency=&#34;true&#34; allow=&#34;encrypted-media&#34; allowFullScreen=&#34;true&#34;>
```

[image: a imagem]

***Aqui vemos a imagem quando insiro o codigo manualmente no campo do mysql e do lado em branco quando insiro via cadastro***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mateus, isso esta acontecendo pois o caractere `"` esta sendo trocado para `&#34;`, isso é normal pois caracteres reservados no HTML são substituídos pela sua [hml entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp). Veja [aqui](http://arquivo.devmedia.com.br/artigos/devmedia/html-entities.html) a lista completa.

Na hora de exibir utilize o método `html_entity_decode` do php, ele irá substituir o código da entity pelo seu simbolo correto.

```
echo html_entity_decode('https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FMarvrikLIVE%2Fvideos%2F386994741992059%2F&show_text=1&width=560&#34; width=&#34;560&#34; height=&#34;483&#34; style=&#34;border:none;overflow:hidden&#34; scrolling=&#34;no&#34; frameborder=&#34;0&#34; allowTransparency=&#34;true&#34; allow=&#34;encrypted-media&#34; allowFullScreen=&#34;true&#34;>');
```

Comment: Essa dica salvou a minha vida, obrigado @Murilo Portugal.